# SQL Update Table Using Table From Another DB

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two different databases. The first, let's call it db_client, contains a table called played_songs. In played_songs, there is a column called song_name.

I have a second database called db_system, which has a table called songs. In the songs table, there is also a column called song_name.

How can I select and update rows in db_system's songs table which have the same song_name as the rows in db_client's played_songs? There is also another column in db_system's songs table which is called image, which I want to set NULL if the song_name from db_system's songs table is in db_client's played_songs table

Comment: Hi, are they on same machine? and what is yor dbms?

Comment: @MohammadMirsafaei They're on Amazon Aurora, compatible with MySQL and PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select columns from different tables BUT the Databases must be in the same server.

```
SELECT   t1.[Column Name]
        ,t1.[Column Name]
        ,t2.[Column Name]
        ,t2.[Column Name]
FROM         [DB1].[table1] t1
        join [DB2].[table2] t2
        on   t1.ID = t2.ID
```

With the INSERT or UPDATE you have to refer in which database exist the table.

```
 Update [DB1].[table1]
 SET    column1 = value1,
        column2 = value2,
 WHERE  [condition]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!